# when I push the space bar, it dumps the full database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code:

```
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"]);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE news_title LIKE '%{$q}%'") or die(mysql_error());
    $tablecount = 0;

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
        while($staff = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo("  

                    {$staff['news_month']}
                    {$staff['news_day']}
                    {$staff['news_year']}
                    &raquo <a href=\"entry/{$staff['id']}\">{$staff['news_title']}</a><br />

            ");                       
        }
    } else {
        echo("Error");
    }
```

So when I push the "space bar" it dumps what all is in my database. I'm stuck on how to not allow the pushing of a space bar empty the data, but again, I'm stuck!

this is my javascript:

```
    function showResult(str){
            if (str.length==0){ 
                  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
                  document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
              return;
            }

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
                else{// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                 }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px solid #A5ACB2";
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","_lib/_php/livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

Comment: You'll get done for not using mysqli or pdo.

Comment: Oh, a space is the least of your problems.

Comment: To expand on @epascarello's comment, you need to read up on [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_InjectionS) and [how to prevent it](http://bobby-tables.com/). If you use unsanitized user provided data in an query as you have done here, you are just asking for someone to steal, modify, and/or delete the data in your database. I'd also recommend learning about [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) attacks. XSS and SQL injection are probably the 2 most common types of attacks any website will face.

Comment: Changing **str.length == 0** to **str.trim().length == 0** in your JavaScript code should resolve your immediate problem; however, you've got bigger fishes to fry though.

Answer (score 2):

Trim the string to remove surrounding spaces.

```
function showResult(str) {
    str = str.trim();
    ...
}
```

Comment: @paxdiablo The `if (str.length == 0)` block returns from the function without doing a query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since all multi-word news titles are likely to contain a space, that's exactly what I'd expect.

If you don't want that to happen, I see two possibilities.

The first is to trap your input values so that it disallows input that doesn't contain a decent search string. You're already doing that for empty strings but you may want to expand it a little.

For example, a minimum number of alpha characters. One alpha character would still allow you to get a lot of articles (search for `e`), even two is a bit iffy (search for `ee` or `ea`). Where you set the threshold will require some analysis on your part - you could, for example, decide to ensure it had at least one vowel and one consonant.

The other option, and this is the one I prefer, is to still allow them to enter whatever they like, but restrict what you give them, such as by adding `limit 250` or equivalent to your query.

You could even tell them about it:

> Your search for 'Kim Kardashian' returned 3,141,592,653,589 items.
>   Only showing first 250.

The *reason* I prefer this one is because it in no way restricts what they can enter (you may well get the rules wrong) but it puts the onus on them to ensure it's not going to grab everything from your database.

This will also stop people scraping your site wholesale and, who knows, maybe you can provide a paid-for service where the limit is increased, if you're that way inclined :-)

Answer (score 0):

So what you've done is said "where the title contains something" and let the user specify "something"

So where '% %' says where the title contains a space.

Do you not want things which contain a space in the title?  Then strip spaces from the search string.  As another user suggested, try using the trim() function to remove spaces only from the end (and thus remove only-space-character queries entirely).

Also, maybe you don't want to select * but instead only a few columns?

P.S. http://laravel.com is your friend.  Also, there's some nice javascript frameworks and libraries that solve lots of problems for you.